# Atom - disable single key binding

Tags: atom-editor

How can I disable a single key binding such as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> in Atom?

I'm using the QWERTZ keyboard layout, so that I execute `pane:increase-size` when I type a '\'.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

1. Open settings with `File > Settings`
2. Click `Keybindings`
3. Filter the list by typing `ctrl-alt-=` in the search box.
4. Click the clipboard icon next to the shortcut. This will copy the shortcut definition to your clipboard.
5. Click the hyperlinked text `your keymap file`.
6. Paste in the contents of the clipboard.
7. Replace `'pane:increase-size'` with the value `'unset!'`

Now `ctrl-alt-=` will not do anything.

EDIT: `'unset!'` was previously `null`, see [this atom discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/disable-default-keybindings/1077/25) for details.

EDIT2: To fix issues with many non-QWERTY keyboard layouts, check out the [keyboard-localization package](https://atom.io/packages/keyboard-localization) for Atom.

Comment: Now, the Keybindings tab shows me both key bindings one doing pane:increase-size and one null

Comment: But try it out... The key combination does nothing, the core definition is overridden by the user definition.

Comment: No, it isn't overridden

Comment: Apparently this can be a problem with non-QWERTY keyboards... I'm still searching for a solution, however my answer does work for QWERTY keyboards.

Comment: @Scriptim Check out this package: [keyboard-localization](https://atom.io/packages/keyboard-localization) - will this solve your problem?

Answer (score 17):

Fix from @Monkey worked, here's the code from my keymap.cson for fixing **backslash**.

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-alt-[': 'unset!'
```

EDIT:
I'm using the QWERTZ keyboard layout.